# bootstrap, complex nested columns with rowspan

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to achieve something like shown in the image below (using Bootstrap 3.3.2)

[image]

I sucessfully created the first block (first image in the image so to speak)
But is it possible to create the design in way, that it automatically transforms to the second design in the image?

I'm struggling with that (not sure if it is even possible).
One important thing to note is, that Ad1 in the first design has to span over the two first rows. Starting row2 below ad1 is unfortunately not an option.

Here is what my first block is made of

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 ">
    <div class="row">
        <div col-sm-4 col-lg-4 ">
            Img1
        </div>
        <div class="news-entry-content col-sm-8 col-lg-8 ">
            Text1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="news-entry-image col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
            Img2
        </div>
        <div class="news-entry-content col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
            Text2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4" title="First News Werbiung">
    Ad1
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

I added the requested  jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/v0r5y7q9/

Just play around with the width.
You'll notice two problems.

1. With a big width: The ad is placed below (Img2+Text2), I want it to place below (Img3+Text3)
2. With a narrow width: (Img3+Text3) is off compared to the other rows. Makes sense, considering how I built the whole thing. One solution to this could be a negative margin. Or is there a better solution?

thanks.

Comment: can you create a fiddle with full code?

Comment: I added a fiddle in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that could be a solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0r5y7q9/3/)

```
see jsfiddle link
```

It's two ad-blocks with visible/hidden, but I've not found a better solution.

p.s. how to put jsfiddle-link directly in the post?

Comment: Here you can find how to add link to your post: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links

Comment: no...really..sorry, but it does not work. I get an error, jsfiddle-link has to be placed as code...i don't know...I just feel stupid...sorry

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is: as soon as you change the img columns to something other than _col-sm-3_ it breaks. 
You can verify that by setting img-column 1 and 2 to _col-sm-4_ and the img-column 3 to something else (_col-sm-3, col-sm-4_).
img-column 3 will be off 
see here: http://jsfiddle.net/evqa96ex/

It kinda makes because the the first two rows are nested and therefore their percentage width-value is computed against their parent which has the class _col-sm-8_

Comment: hmm..yes.. it does not work. then I think, you need an additional class for your special case: http://jsfiddle.net/k4at3foe/

you have to calculate the width for css before. In this case: 0,6667*0,3333=0,2222

Comment: here example for col-sm-5: http://jsfiddle.net/k4at3foe/1/ so you need to calculate: 0,6667*0,416667=0,27779

Comment: thanks for your efforts!

@readers
Please also see Alvaro Menéndez' solution. Depending on your needs, it may suit you better

Answer (score 1):

If the height of your elements on your project are fixed I would use this turnaround to get what you want. Just change your add to absolute position when you want and place it at the bottom of  your elements. Like in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1v4ttuk/)**

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 500px) {

    .ad1 {
     position:absolute;
     /*and bottom:x based on the height of your elements*/

}}
```